# How to git clone specific linux kernel build

Tags: linux, git, kernel

I know I can git clone the linux kernel using the following:

```
git clone \
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git \
linux-2.6
```

But I'm wondering how to clone a specific build of an older kernel - say 2.6.39.4?

http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/branches/ appears to be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you clone a git repository, you get the full history going back to when it was first created.  You can check out any revision you see in the `git log` ( or browse using `gitk` ) using `git checkout`.  Each time the kernel is released, it is also tagged so you can use the tag to check out that release instead of having to look up the hash.  For instance, `git checkout v2.6.39`.  You can see the available tags with `git tag`.